# Why are odd moments of Normal distribution equal to 0

Tags: taylor-expansion, exponential-function, normal-distribution, moment-generating-functions

I am studying the topic of MGF and have come across the result that odd moments of $N(0,1)$ are $0,$ yet I cannot see why.

Given $\mu_k$ the $k$-th moment and from the fact that:

\begin{equation}
M(t)=e^{t^2/2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{2k}}{2^k  k!}
\end{equation}
They claim that

> Odd powers of $t$ are all $0$

Therefore $\mu_k = 0$ and $\mu_{2k} = \frac{(2k)!}{2^k k!}$

I cannot see why that is true.

Thanks a lot for any hint.

Comment: Look at its density function. ($\mu_k = E[X^{k}]$ by definition). In Riemann integal representation you'll have $E[X^{k}]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{k}f(x)dx$. Now looking back at density function, you'll see that the function under integral sign is odd ($g(-x)=-g(x)$) (meaning that for any symmetric interval (against $0$) you'll have the same values in both sides but with different signs, making the whole integral $0$).

Comment: I wonder whether I understand this question. You have a sum in which the powers of $t$ that appear are all of the form $t^{2k},$ i.e. they are even powers of $t.$ Are you asking how they arrived at that particular sum where you see only even powers of $t\text{?}$

Comment: Because a normal is symmetric.

Comment: Hi, thanks to everyone. I got to understand it better, thanks to @kolobokish for your alternative view, it was useful to me to think it that way. Also Michael Harry made me notice that it was kind of evident from the equation itself, but I wasn't interpreting it properly. Thank you both.